# Sesiones PHP y MYSQL para distintos niveles de usuarios

Tags: php, mysql, sesiones

espero me puedan ayudar, quiero agregar restricciones dependiendo del nivel del usuario, pero no logro que funcione, mi código en el home antes de iniciar es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
$varsesion= $_SESSION['usuario'];
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];
if($varsesion== null || $varsesion=''){
    header("location:index.html");
    die();
}
?>
```

Después de esto ya se muestra todo, pero quiero que específicamente en un enlace solo tenga acceso el usuario con nivel 1 y lo pongo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php if($nivel == 1) { ?>

    <a href="#">Cuentas totales</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Pero sigue sin aparecerme ese enlace ya en la página final, no se si tengo un error al enlazar la sesión con esto $nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];

De antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Y cómo haces llegar la variable `$nivel` al archivo donde creas el condicional para evaluarla?

Comment: mediante la variable 
session_start();
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];

y tengo otro archivo en donde creo la sesión 

$consulta="SELECT*FROM usuarios where usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$encriptacionSHA1'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

Estoy medio perdido

Comment: A lo que voy es que parece que $nivel se declara y recibe el valor de la sesión en un archivo y posterior se pretende usar en otro archivo ¿es así?, de ser ese el caso insisto en la pregunta, ¿cómo haces que dicha variable esté disponible en el contexto del segundo archivo?

Comment: Ahhh, no sé, tal vez eso es lo que estoy haciendo mal, soy nuevo haciendo esto, ¿Sabes como lo puefo arreglar?

Comment: no es que lo estas haciendo mal es que no estas haciando lo que debes hacer... que has investigado al respecto sobre pasar variables o datos de sesion en php???

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas hacer un ***session_start();*** en tu pagina de llegada para que de esta manera hacer uso de las variables de session, una vez en ella debes realizar la validación antes de mostrar el contenido y luego si se cumplen las condiciones muestras el contenido de lo contrario lo enviás nuevamente al archivo inicial.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) || ($_SESSION['nivel']!=1) ) {
     header("location:index.php");
     } else
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
..
..
</html>
<? }
?>
```

También hay que mencionar que tus archivos deben ser .php para poder usar las variables de sesion, es mas sencillo crear el html desde php que a la inversa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, así ya me funcionó

Comment: @alejandro si esta respuesta te sirve favor marca como resuelta.!!